# Nativescript - iOS build error message

Tags: nativescript

Getting this error message, on iOS app build (edited for clarity).

Any help?

```html
objc[5636]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both 

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x119d0ecc0) and 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x119b256f0).

One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

`tns platform remove ios
 tns platform add ios`